# Send XHR request without receiving any data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make a very simple script that should keep me logged on a site, that deletes your session after 10 minutes of inactivity. This is quite simple, as follows:

```
//Silently "refresh" the page - at least server thinks you refreshed, thus you're active
function call() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //Load current url
    req.open("GET",location.href,true);
    //Try to only send the data! (does not work - the browser also receives data)
    req.onprogress = function() {
      this.abort();  //Abort request
      wait(); //Wait another 5 minutes
    }

    //Repeat request instantly if it fails
    req.onerror = call;
    //Send
    req.send();
}
function wait() {
  //5minutes timeout
  setTimeout(call,5000);
}
wait();
```

This works perfectly but the requests seem to load completely. Though the page is small, I want to make this clean and prevent downloading the data. This means, I want to stop loading just after the data starts downloading. Or better - after the data has been sent.

Is there a way to make such "ping" function?

Comment: You could use HEAD method, server will return headers without body. But site may not handle HEAD or extend session. Also you make requests every 5 second, you can make bigger interval.

Comment: 5 second is a debug interval, for real application, I will use 300 seconds which is half of the session time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
         console.log( this.readyState );
         if( this.readyState == 2 ) { //sent, otherwise it raises an error
               console.log( 'aborting...' );
               this.abort()
         }

         if( this.readyState == 4 ) {
                console.log( this.responseText );
         }
    }
    req.open( 'get', .... );
    req.send();
```

prints:

```
 1
 2
 aborting...
 3
 4
 undefined
```

I am not completely sure with this, but I guess that by aborting the request aborts the download and retrieval of data, but all other states are triggered. I try this with a large image which was not cached and the request was done very quickly, without any result.

BTW. To just send a »ping« to your server you can also set the `src` of an image tag to the desired script, this will trigger the request too.

Comment: Setting `src` to an image will make the server download the image. This method is used to preload images to cache.

Comment: setting the `src` of an image will make the browser download it from the server, but one can let this `src` point to a (probaly php) script which will be executed. No data needs to be returned...

Comment: My point wasn't to prevent some sort of data returning, but to prevent *downloading* data from the server. It doesn't matter what the target is, the data will be downloaded anyway.